# Shortest Path from city 0 to N (by road/ by Air mixed cost)

Tags: c#, algorithm

Okay, I need a nudge in the right direction. I have an array of costs of travelling from city 0 to N and an array of costs of travelling from city 0 to N by flight. I have a limit K on the number of flights I can take when travelling.
For example

```
N = 3 // there are 3 cities to be visited 0->1 ->2 ->3 in consecutive order
roadTime = { 1, 2, 3};
flightTime = { 2, 1, 6};
K = 2; //take a maximum of 2 flights
```

I am allowed to travel all by road or use some road and at most K flights and find the minimum cost of travelling from 0 to 3 in the example.

What I tried:

Started out by hand trying to find a possible solution and came up with a binary tree but couldn't represent the tree structure in code (C#) without pulling my hair out - I'm too new to graphs to even think about applying them. But in the process of working it out I then I stumbled on an idea and, thinking I had nailed it, I realized I could find the permutations of the trip from 0 to N with a mix of road cost and flight cost to get the minimum cost:

```
public int minTime(int N, int[] roadTime, int[] flightTime, int K)
    {
        int n = 0;
        int min = roadTime.Sum();
        while (K > 0)
        {
            char[] s = (new string('A', N - K) + new string('B', K)).ToCharArray();
            do
            {
                n = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (s[i] == 'A')
                    {
                        n += roadTime[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        n += flightTime[i];
                    }
                }
                min = (n < min) ? n : min;
            } while (permute(s));
            K--;
        }
        return min;
    }
    public Boolean permute(char[] a)
    {
        int N = a.Length, i = N - 2;
        for (; i >= 0; i--)
            if (a[i] < a[i + 1])
                break;
        if (i < 0) return false;

        for (int j = N - 1; j >= i; j--)
        {
            if (a[j] > a[i])
            {
                var temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < (N + i + 1) / 2; j++)         
        {
            var temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[N + i - j];
            a[N + i - j] = temp;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

This works fine but naturally as N is > than 12, there is factorial growth in the number of permutations of the costs. My solution works well up to about 15 cities in reasonable time. I need to find a way to solve this problem so that I can find a minimum cost for 1 to no less than 50 cities.

Even thinking about it intuitively, how can you be sure that you have a minimum of anything if you haven't tried them all?

The idea of permutations is stuck in my head for now so I'm finding it hard to see another way other than through my present 'rose coloured glasses'. I need a nudge to a totally new line of thinking.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT!!! 18/May/2014:**

Found the answer after a nudge in the right direction from Dukeling. Hope someone else finds this useful

```
public int minTime(int N, int[] roadTime, int[] flightTime, int K)
    {
        int n = 0;
        int min = roadTime.Sum();
        do
        {
            n = 0;
            var sortedDict = (from entry in cost(roadTime, flightTime, N)
                              orderby entry.Value descending
                              where entry.Value > 0 select entry 
                  ).Take(K)
                  .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                if (sortedDict.ContainsKey(i))
                {
                    n += flightTime[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    n += roadTime[i];
                }
            }
            min = (n < min) ? n : min;
            K--;
        } while (K > 0);

        return min;
    }
    static Dictionary<int, int> cost (int[] a1, int[] a2, int N)
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> d = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            d.Add(i, a1[i] - a2[i]);
        }
        return d;
    }
```

Comment: I don't really see the graph in your question. If I understand correctly, the optimum routes by road and air on each leg of the journey are already given, so for your example you shoud visit the three cities by road, air and air respectively for a total travelling time of 5 and not exhausting your flight limit, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is pick flights for at most `K` routes where it will give the biggest improvement (and obviously not pick any more if there aren't any more that would result in an improvement).

So, in your example:

```
roadTime   = { 1, 2, 3};
flightTime = { 2, 1, 6};
improvement    -1 1  -3
```

The only one that shows an improvement (and thus also the biggest improvement) is the second one, so we pick the flight for that one.

Hint - a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) might help. No graphs required.

Comment: Looks good, but I think the logic might be back to front.  He should probably only fly for the second one, to give the shortest total time of 1+1+3=5.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Ah, yes, thanks. I wasn't paying enough attention.

Comment: dude, you have just blown my mind open. Let me see what I can come up with and run some test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, I would like to offer the [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach as a vision of your problem.

Assume, that we have a function, which defines the cost for getting to the city, having some number of allowed fly attempts (and unlimited road attempts).

So, the cost of getting to the some city, is depends on the cost of getting to the previous city and number of allowed fly attempts:

```
Cost(cityNum, flyAttempts) = 
    min(
       Cost(cityNum - 1, flyAttempts)    + roadTimeTo[cityNum], // moving by road
       Cost(cityNum - 1, flyAttempts - 1) + flyTimeTo[cityNum], // moving by fly
    );
```

The base of Dynamic Programming, is:

```
1) Cost of getting to the starting city: 
Cost[0, n] = 0 // n - is any number

2) Cost of getting to any city, when there are no fly attempts: 
Cost[n, 0] = Cost[n - 1, 0] + roadCost[n] // n - is any number
```

We can use bottom-up Dynamic Programming, to solve your problem (I will provide valid Java solution):

```java
public class Fly {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int citiesNum = 4;
        int flyAttempts = 2;
        int[] roadCost = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] flyCost = new int[] { 2, 1, 6 };

        int shortestWay =
                shortestWay(roadCost, flyCost, citiesNum, flyAttempts);

        System.out.println(shortestWay);
    }

    public static int shortestWay(
            int[] roadCost,
            int[] flyCost,
            int citiesNum,
            int flyAttempts) {

        // Cost matrix
        int[][] cost = new int[citiesNum][flyAttempts + 1];

        int lastCity = citiesNum - 1;

        // Initializing base conditions of Dynamic Programming
        for (int i = 0; i <= flyAttempts; i++) {
            cost[0][i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= lastCity; i++) {
            cost[i][0] = cost[i - 1][0] + roadCost[i - 1];
        }

        // Calculating cost matrix
        for (int i = 1; i <= lastCity; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= flyAttempts; j++) {
                cost[i][j] = Math.min(
                        cost[i - 1][j] + roadCost[i - 1],
                        cost[i - 1][j - 1] + flyCost[i - 1]);
            }
        }

        return cost[lastCity][flyAttempts];
    }
}
```

Comment: This runs a lot faster than my code and uses about 1/3rd less memory, good job. Still wrapping my head around the derived function though.